# How to scale mass and time for best results with box2d?

Tags: box2d

I know it's best to scale the moving objects into the 0.1 - 10 meters range. Do we need to scale time and mass, too, for best results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to set the sizes of bodies in the range from 0.1 to 10 meters due to the fact that box2d uses a dynamic tree to arrange bodies and work with them efficiently. If the bodies are large, box2d spends a lot of time writing bodies to the cells of the dynamic tree. If the bodies are small, the advantage of using a dynamic tree is lost. The mass and the value of the time step do not affect the work of box2d. But it is not recommended to create bodies with a large mass difference that have to collide with each other.